# Why is offsetof(member) equal to sizeof(struct)?

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof, offsetof

I have a struct defined as:

```
struct smth
{
    char a;
    int b[];
};
```

When I call `sizeof` and `offsetof` on this struct:

```
cout << sizeof(struct smth) << endl;
cout << offsetof(struct smth, b) << endl;
```

Output is:

```
4
4
```

How come when the size of the stuct is 4 and char is using 1 byte, the offset of the int array is 4?
Why is there some kind of padding? 
Also, why isn't the int array occupying any space at all?

Comment: You mean `offsetof(struct smth, b)`, right?

Comment: @CarlNorum Yes, I do. Edited.

Comment: Is it C or C++? They are different.

Comment: @YuHao I am asking specifically for C++ but added c tag so people can find it with that tag as well. How are they different w.r.t. the answer of this question?

Comment: @biox6 You should tag the question with only the tag that's relative. C and C++ may be similar in many fields, they are different in more. In this question, e.g, variable length arrays are only valid in C, not C++.

Comment: @biox6 make it an b[1]; to see differences

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How come when the size of the stuct is 4 and char is using 1 byte, the offset of the int array is 4? Why is there some kind of padding?

There is padding because the C standard allows it; the compiler often aligns variables to improve performance.

> Also, why isn't the second variable occupying any space at all (which seems like the case)?

It's a C99 flexible array member - that's the entire point of it.  The idea is to allocate your structure something like:

```
struct smth *s = malloc(sizeof *s + 10 * sizeof s->b[0]);
```

And then you'd have a structure that operates as if `b` were a 10-element array.

Comment: What kind of performance improvements does this allow? Just curious.

Comment: @biox6, some processors load instructions can only load words from word-aligned addresses.  If you have a word at an unaligned address, you'd need to load each byte separately and recombine.

Comment: Your allocation statement does not consider alignment constraints. In general it will fail to allocate the correct amount of memory. You would instead allocate a properly sized structure using `struct smth *s = malloc(offsetof(struct smth, b[10]));`.

Comment: @IInspectable, how so?  `malloc` is required to return safely-aligned pointers, and the structure is laid out correctly.  What's the difference?

Comment: probably `10 * sizeof s->b[0]`

Comment: I'm sorry, brain-lag. I had [something else altogether](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/26/220873.aspx) in mind. Consider it an *alternative* way to calculate the size rather than a *correction*. The trailing zero-sized array being part of the struct ensures proper alignment.

Answer (score 3):

Because the size of the member `b` is zero, and the compiler adds padding between the `a` and `b` members so that `b` is on a "word" boundary.

However, if I remember correctly having a flexible array in a structure like that is only valid C, not C++ except as a compiler extension.

Comment: here is this  `int b[]` equivalent to int *b?

Comment: No it is not. `int* b` would make the `sizeof(smth)` larger, and the extra space would be where address of some int variable is to be stored. Instead, `int b[]` says the structure shall be allocated dynamically with some (unknown at compile time) number of integers as a single memory block.

Comment: @mity How do you assign value(s) to the variable `b`,could you give me the assignment statement

Comment: @Light See the answer from Carl Norum.

Comment: @Light: Given `struct smth *s = malloc(sizeof(*s) + 10*sizeof(*s->b));`, you can write `s->a = 'c'; s->b[0] = 0; s->b[9] = 9;`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since OP comments that the question is C++:

```
struct smth
{
    char a;
    int b[];
};
```

An array like `b[]` is invalid in C++. The array must have fixed size. Variable length arrays are only valid in C99.

Assuming that your compiler supports it as extension, the array `b[]` has a size of zero, which makes the struct containing only a `char` member. The the rule of padding in `struct` works, padding the `struct` to a word, which is 4 bytes in your machine.